# apache2 install via chef-solo on Ubuntu 18.04 failing

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I am trying to install apache2 via chef-solo unsuccessfully. The same recipe works when I run chef-client in local mode.

```
package 'apache2' do
  action [:$pstall]
end
and 
package 'apache2'
```

both fail, with the following exception:

```
* apt_update[Update the apt cache daily] action periodic (up to date)
* apt_package[apache2] action install

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'apt_package[apache2]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
---- Begin output of ["apt-get", "-q", "-y", "install", "apache2=2.4.29-1ubuntu4.4"] ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
---- End output of ["apt-get", "-q", "-y", "install", "apache2=2.4.29-1ubuntu4.4"] ----
Ran ["apt-get", "-q", "-y", "install", "apache2=2.4.29-1ubuntu4.4"] returned 100
```

The fact that chef-solo is able to execute the first line in the recipe, means configuration should be fine. I am not sure what I am missing. Please, any pointers are appreciated.

Best,

Alice

Comment: Based on the provided log - `E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?`. From which user you are running chef-solo?

Comment: I used chef-solo -c solo.rb -j web.json. After seeing your comment, I ran it as sudo. Seems to have resolved that issue. I am running into a different issue now, but that's probably me.

Comment: Apparently, chef didn't like    solo.rb and     web.json specified as relative paths. I gave the full path in the above command. Worked like a charm, just in case any one else runs into the same issue.

Comment: @SzymonSzypulski, I cannot accept this as the answer, as it is a comment. It solved my issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the historical reference, issue was solved as [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959050/apache2-install-via-chef-solo-on-ubuntu-18-04-failing?noredirect=1#comment92847198_52959050).

Chef solo should be run from the root user or with the use of sudo.